# Print First 400 characters of an opened file in python

Tags: python

I have calculated how many total characters are in a python file.  I want to print to the console just the first 400 of them, which is where I am stuck.  the output should be in the same format as in my file - still words in sentences and what not.

```
file=open(my_file.txt)
nchar=0
for i in file:
    word=i.rstrip()
    nchar=nchar+len(i)
    #nchar=15000
..................
print '1st 400 chars of this file here'
```

Comment: why not use indices `print open(file).read()[:400]`?

Comment: @AshokaLella: Because he's already at the end of the file and will read nothing. And if he hadn't, it would be silly to read, say, a 500MB file into memory to just print the first 400 characters.

Comment: As a side note, you should always `close` a file when you open it—or, better yet, use a `with` statement so you don't have to remember (and so you don't have to be careful with exceptions, etc.) In a quick&dirty script that exists as soon as it's done with the file, it doesn't make much difference, but it's still a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 4):

If you hadn't already read the whole file in a loop, this would be trivial:

```
print f.read(400)
```

The [`read`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#file.read) method reads exactly as many bytes/characters as you ask for, or fewer if the file is too small.

Fortunately, since this is a real file (as opposed to, say, a socket wrapper, or a file-like object provided by some library), you can always [`seek`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) back to the start:

```
f.seek(0)
print f.read(400)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `read()` method and slicing:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    print f.read()[:400]
```

This will print the first `400` characters, *including new-line characters*.

Comment: Why would you read the whole file just to print the first 400 characters of it?

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer is to just seek back to the start of the file (or even close and re-open it). But if you're worried that seems too inefficient or clunky or something, there is an alternative: Just keep track of them as you go along.

```
file=open('my_file.txt')
nchar=0
contents=''
for i in file:
    word=i.rstrip()
    nchar=nchar+len(i)
    if len(contents) < 400:
        contents += i
```

Now, you may have *more* than 400 characters (by up to a line's worth), but you won't have *less* (unless the whole file was shorter than 400 characters, in which case presumably you *want* to have less). So, you can just slice the first 400 of whatever you've got:

```
print(contents[:400])
```